# Вопрос по навешиванию событий jQuery

Tags: jquery, события, ajax

На странице имеются ссылки вида :

```
<a href="/music.html"><div class="link">Музыка</div></a>
```

Есть аякс-функция на jQuery,которая будет в блок с id="ajaxDаtа" загружать url страницы,найденной в аттрибуте href ссылки.

Как привесить событие к ссылкам,так,чтобы при нажатии на ссылку выполнялся ajax-запрос,а не переход по ссылке?

Comment: Благодарю,всё получилось)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $('a').live('click',function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
            yourAjaxFunction(url);
        return false;
    });
```

Соответственно, код самих ссылок исправлять не придется, более того новые появившиеся ссылки автоматически подпадут под действие данного кода, благодаря функции live()

Если вам нужно так обрабатывать не все ссылки, то замените селектор $('a') на нужный вам(например добавьте класс AJAX-ссылкам), либо делайте проверку уже внутри данной функции, и не вызывайте yourAjaxFunction, а также возвращайте true.

Тогда ссылка отработает как обычная, а не AJAX

Comment: И все-таки уточную, для будущих поколений :) для приведенного кода live'у было бы более безопасно дать селектор $('a > div.link') - дабы не задеть другие ссылки на странице

Answer (score 2):

допустим есть функция

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function doSomething(aObj)
  {
    // твой ajax тут, aObj -  DOM объект нажатой <a>
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Твоя ссылка будет выглядеть так

```
<a href="/music.html" onClick='return doSomething(this);'><div class="link">Музыка</div></a>
```